# How to clear weblogic cache

Tags: caching, weblogic8.x

I want to know how to clear weblogic cache without rebooting my Weblogic 8.1 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the application stage directory. Undeploy your application, delete the contents of the stage directory and redeploy your app. Hope this helps